# Google sheet Script issue

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to replicate a spreadsheet I saw online with modifications.  The purpose of the spreadsheet is to document my Bull Put/Bear Call credit spreads.  The plan is to have a dashboard sheet where I can enter the info and by clicking the add position button, it will transfer the info into the data sheet where all logs will be held.  I will also be able to close positions from the dashboard page, but I have not even begun that script as of yet.  The script I am putting together is.

```
function AddPosition() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dashboard = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var data = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var expiration = dashboard.getRange(7, 3).getValue();
  var sym = dashboard.getRange(7, 4).getValue();
  var contracts = dashboard.getRange(7, 5).getValue();
  var type = dashboard.getRange(7, 6).getValue();
  var shortleg = dashboard.getRange(7, 7).getValue();
  var longleg = dashboard.getRange(7, 8).getValue();
  var pop = dashboard.getRange(7, 9).getValue();
  var credit = dashboard.getRange(7, 10).getValue();

if (expiration=="" ||
    sym=="" || 
    contracts=="" || 
    type=="" || 
    shortleg=="" || 
    longleg=="" || 
    pop=="" || 
    credit=="" || {
      **var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.**
      var response = ui.alert('Missing data','Please fill in missing values and try again.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
      return;
}

  data.insertRowAfter(data.getLastRow());
  var lastRow = data.getLastRow();
  var now = new Date();
   data.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(now);
   data.getRange(lastRow, 2).setValue(sym);
   data.getRange(lastRow, 3).setValue(type);
   data.getRange(lastRow, 4).setValue(expiration);
   data.getRange(lastRow, 6).setValue(longleg);
   data.getRange(lastRow, 7).setValue(shortleg);
   data.getRange(lastRow, 9).setValue(contracts);
   data.getRange(lastRow, 10).setValue(credit);
   data.getRange(lastRow, 13).setValue(pop);

   data.getRange(lastRow-1, 33).copyTo(data.getRange(lastRow, 33));
   data.getRange(lastRow-1, 34).copyTo(data.getRange(lastRow, 34));
   data.getRange(lastRow-1, 35).copyTo(data.getRange(lastRow, 35));
   data.getRange(lastRow-1, 36).copyTo(data.getRange(lastRow, 36));
   data.getRange(lastRow-1, 37).copyTo(data.getRange(lastRow, 37));

  dashboard.getRange(7,2,1,11 ).clearContent();

}
```

On line 23 `var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();` // Same variations.
I keep getting

> SyntaxError:Unexpected identifier line:23 file: Code Gs

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Basically, I'm trying say if data is missing, an alert will fire stating *"'Missing data','Please fill in missing values and try again.'"*

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I saw a few missing parenthesis within your `if-else` statement and also a few asterisks "*" on the declared var. Fixed it up and it executed properly on my end.

Try this:

```
if (expiration=="" ||
sym=="" || contracts=="" || type=="" || shortleg=="" || longleg=="" || pop=="" || credit=="") {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); //Same variations.
var response = ui.alert('Missing data','Please fill in missing values and try again.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, 
Probably after I wrote this I found the missing parenthesis behind Pop.  I removed the "||" and added the ")" at the end and the error went away.  The "*" were to emphasize where the error was taking place.  But thank you.